# Handle the sum results of ireport group

Tags: jasper-reports

I created a group that is separated by type, and there are two types: "revenue" and "outlay". I have a text field called "foreseen" and i have a variable that makes the sum of the foreseen for "revenue" and "outlay", and displays the result of both. I want to get the sum result foreseen and subtract by sum result outlay.
I couldn't do that cause it's one variable that displays both results sum

Is there a way to do that using groups like i told above?

Comment: Just do the subtract directly in the textField? $V{foreseen}-$V{outlay}, set evaluationTime="report" and you are done..

Comment: If you need an answer you need to pass the jrxml definition of the variables so I can see the class (for correct expression), then just ping me